# Is there a recipe for expanding a flexi-page region to the full page size or is that "just not a thing" in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, page-template, responsive-design, form-factor

Because a lot of editing is done on one of the regions of a page template, I'd like to be able to expand that region to the full page size.

But even with the reporting dashboard the 4 arrow icons:

[image: image showing 4 arrow icons]

expand the content into a modal rather than expending the page region in place.

1. Is the in-place expansion just not a thing in Lightning?
2. Anyone seen/have a recipe to construct a custom template for this? First thought is to have a second flexi-page and the button toggles between the multi-region flexi-page and a single full page flexi-page, but not sure what would happen to any unsaved edits.

There is conditional rendering based on the form factor on a component but when the component is not rendered the screen space is just blank.